# Leibniz's rule and proving that $x(t)$ satisfies integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

The question is:

> Show that if $x(t)$ satisfies the integral equation $$x(t) = a + bt + \int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(x(s))ds $$ then $x(t)$ is a solution to the initial value problem $$x''(t) = f(x(t))$$ for $t>0$, with $x(0) = a, x'(0) = b.$

This is what I've done and I'm not sure if it's even remotely correct.
$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(a + bt + \int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(x(s))ds\right) \\ x'(t) = b + \frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(x(s))ds\right)  \\ x'(t) = b + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(t-s)f(x(s))ds \\ x'(t) = b + \int_{0}^{t} f(x(s)) + \frac{\partial f(x(s))}{\partial t}(t-s)\frac{\partial x(s)}{\partial t} ds \qquad \text{by chain rule and product rule} $$
Then I take the derivative again, and I don't seem to get the required result. Can someone tell me if I did something wrong and guide me in the correct way?

Comment: You differentiate the integrand wrongly. You should have $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big[(t-s)f(x(s))\Big] = f(x(s))$.

Comment: Why is it this? Don't I have to employ the product rule and the chain rule?

Comment: Nothing like that. Recall that in computing partial derivatives, we treat the other variables as "constant".

Comment: Right. How silly. But then for the second derivative step, that means bringing the differentiation under the integral, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x(s))ds$ will also vanish won't it? (I know that we can just use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus instead, but why does bringing it in make it zero?

Comment: The term that you wrote vanishes indeed, but you forgot the ``boundary term" when you apply Leibniz rule: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^t f(x(s))\, ds = f(x(t))\frac{d}{dt}(t) - f(x(0))\frac{d}{dt}(0) + \int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x(s))\, ds $

Comment: Thanks. I assume this is the general formula for Leibniz's. I think we only covered the simplest case.  
One last question - In the original expression of $x(t)$, say I didn't use Leibniz's rule, and just used fundamental theorem of calculus. Won't I get $x'(t) = 0 + b + 0$? Because  
$x'(t) = b + \frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^{t} g(s) ds$ where $g(s)$ is the integrand. Then $x'(t) = b + \frac{d}{dt} [G(t) - G(0)] = b + G'(t) + 0 = b + g(t) = b + 0$ since there's that $(t-s)$ factor?

Comment: The integrand is a function of $t$ and $s$.

Comment: Would we have to employ the multi-variate chain rule then for $G(t,s)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\frac{d}{dt} \int^t_0 f(s)ds = f(t)$. If you use Leibniz's rule, you would get the analogous $\frac{d}{dt} \int^t_0 f(x(s))ds = f(x(t))$ since $f(x(t))$ can be thought of as $f(x,t)$.

To your question, what you miss is a product rule. It's slightly easier to see this way.
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}x(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(a + bt + \int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(x(s))ds\right)\\
&= b + \frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)f(x(s))ds\right)\\
&= b + \frac{d}{dt} \left(t\int_{0}^{t}f(x(s))ds\right) - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{0}^{t}sf(x(s))ds\right) \\
&= b + \left(\int_{0}^{t}f(x(s))ds + t f(x(t)) \right) - tf(x(t))\\
&= b + \int_{0}^{t}f(x(s))ds
\end{align}
It follows that $x'' = f(x(t))$.

Note that if you use the full version of Leibniz's rule, which is
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} f(t,x) dx = f(t,b(t))\frac{db(t)}{dt} - f(t,a(t)) \frac{da(t)}{dt} + \int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t) dx$$
with $b(t) = t$ and $a(t) = 0$. You would get the same.

On to your question about the factor $(t - s)$, This does not work because your function $g(s)$ is not the same as $g(s,t)$. Note that last integral above (it's a partial derivative instead). For example, $\frac{d}{dt} g(t) = g'(t)$ but $\frac{d}{dt} g(x(t)) = g'(x(t)) x'(t)$. Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is usually written in 1-dimension, Leibniz's rule is its generalization.

Comment: Cheers. Sorry if this is a repost, because I replied but I don't think it showed up. I udnerstand your process and I also tried FTC, but I have the dilemna of evaluating it as zero since there's a $(t-s)$ factor in the integrand. I was wondering if you could clear up my misconception? (The misconception is in the other comment thread).

Comment: I see. I will edit my post to comment on the $(t-s)$ factor.

Answer (score 2):

If you know convolution (notation *), here is a proof based on the following facts

- $(u*v)'=u'*v,$
- the derivative of the Heaviside function $1_{x>0}$ is $\delta$ distribution,
- $\delta$ is neutral for convolution: $\delta*\varphi=\varphi$.

Let us write the integral equation under the form:

$$\tag{1}x(t)=a+bt+t*f(x(t))$$

Let us differentiate (1):

$$\tag{2}x'(t)=b+(t')*f(x(t))=b+1_{x>0}*f(x(t))$$

Let us differentiate (2):

$$\tag{3}x''(t)=(1_{x>0})'*f(x(t))=\delta*f(x(t))=f(x(t))$$

Comment: Thanks, we haven't learnt convolution but I'll sure to save this comment as well for future purposes.

Comment: Nice overkill! (+1)

Comment: @ Niklas Hebestreit Thanks. One of the interests of this site is to have different levels of answer. On this aspect, I have appreciated the positive attitude of the OP saying that he hasn't learned these notions but is awared in this way that such notions exist and that, later on, he will be able to work with them.